# Javascript script error code 0 -- Object required

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a php file on my web server and it is being displayed through a VB.NET program using the "web browser", and seeing some people still use IE as their default web browser they are getting this error every time they launch the program. Anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
      function Toggle(image, list)
      {
        var listElementStyle = document.getElementById(list).style;
        if (listElementStyle.display == "none")
        {
          listElementStyle.display = "block";
          document.getElementById(image).src="./images/minus.png";
          document.getElementById(image).alt="Close";
        }
        else
        {
          listElementStyle.display="none";
          document.getElementById(image).src="./images/plus.png";
          document.getElementById(image).alt="Open";
        }
      }
      function TreeInit(nodes)
      {
        var counter;
        for( counter = 1; counter <= nodes; counter++ )
        {
          document.getElementById('childList' + counter).style.display="none";
        }
      }
    </SCRIPT>
```

TreeInit is called later at the bottom of my webpage.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
    TreeInit(4)
</SCRIPT>
```

I've added a `;` after `TreeInit(4)`

The error was that I only had two children, not 4. Changed `TreeInit(4);` to `TreeInit(2);` and all is well. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Would adding a `;` behind `TreeInit(4)` help?

Comment: add the ; as passerby says, it should work. We fixed our IE issues by adding something like 10-12 ";" in our js :-/

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo _"We fixed our IE issues..."_ should be "We fixed our bad JS design..." :)

Comment: @Andreas sssshhhh. My boss reads SO. (My boss' favourite dev also wrote all the js!) :P

Comment: @Passerby added a `;` behind `TreeInit(4)` still giving error.

The error is saying that line 69 is the cause which is this line:
          `document.getElementById('childList' + counter).style.display="none";`

Comment: @user1752701 Please update your new code and new error into your question, as comment is short and inconvenience. And make sure you have corresponding `#childList1~4` element on your page.

Comment: @Passerby Thank you, post has been updated and you lead me to the problem. I appreciate it very much my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Made sure I had the correct number of child lists, now the errors have vanished.